# Typetraits and specific behaviour

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, type-traits

Consider the followint template:

```
template<class T>
void doStuff(const T& a)
    {
    if(std::is_copy_assignable<T>::value)
        {
        T x;
        x=a;
        printf("Hello\n");
        }
    else
        {
        printf("Goodbye\n");
        }
    }
```

This fails to compile even though the "Hello" part is never run for non-copy-assignable types. What should I do instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a tag dispatch based way to solve your problem:

```
template<class T>
void doStuffHelper(const T& a, std::true_type can_copy_assign)
{
  T x;
  x=a;
  printf("Hello\n");
}
template<class T>
void doStuffHelper(const T& a, std::false_type can_copy_assign)
{
  printf("Goodbye\n");
}
template<class T>
void doStuff(const T& a)
{
  return doStuffHelper( a, std::is_copy_assignable<T>() );
}
```

here, only the version that works is compiled.  The name of `can_copy_assign` exists merely for documentation -- the point is that I override based on `std::is_copy_assignable<T>()`, and I use override dispatch to pick which implementation I am going to use.

In your code, the `if` block becomes something like `if(true)`.  The `else` clause of an `if` block that is `if(true)` *still has to compile*, which means the methods used have to be valid, even though they will never run.

The tag dispatch solution arranges it so that functions with the expected properties are compiled with the code that uses the properties.

Similar methods involving SFINAE can be used, but SFINAE has some annoying complications that mean it is usually best to avoid it, if possible.

Comment: I would add 'Avoid it if possible', but there are many a case where it can't be avoided.

Comment: @DaveS yes, it isn't always possible to avoid it: but it is usually best if you can.  I've posted a SFINAE solution or two to Stack Overflow in the past.  ;)